# Returning min/max value on a sublist without using built-ins?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python, and am a bit confused with finding an int max/min value with a sublist. Example below

Firstly, the data set im using is a list with lists as elements. It looks like - [[John, Smith, 15], [Yu, Harold, 16]] etc.. Im having trouble getting just the INT as the max or min value from the list. I have tried the following

```
def get_largest_sale(ret_data):
        return max(ret_data)
```

And get the max value but using the strings instead of the ideal int. How would I code it so it interprets it as: "Get the largest numerical value in the list/sublists?" Without returning a string or other incomplete numbers?
Thank you.
Ive also tried for loops but am not well versed enough to creatively find a way to use it.

EDIT - the input would be

```
[['Daniel', 'Cochran', '274000'], ['Franklin', 'Smith', '199200'], ['Miguel', 'Espinoza', '252000'], ['Joseph', 'Miller', '610300']
```

and since Joseph has the highest numerical value, the output would ideally be:

```
['Joseph', 'Miller', '610300']
```

Comment: So you want to find the min/max based on the string versions of the numbers?

Comment: Pls show your input and desired output as actual Python data strucures that one can copy'n'paste.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, and where did you fail? Sounds very much like double loop would do the trick.

Comment: @expressjs123 Im gonna post desired output

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I have tried a for loop iterating on each sublist but am unsure of what to put. I put the desired outcome up there if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the entire sub list with the max value, use a key function with `max`:

```
def get_largest_sale(ret_data):
    return max(ret_data, key=lambda sub: int(sub[2]))

>>> get_largest_sale(data)
['Joseph', 'Miller', '610300']
```

Comment: Thank you, I am unfamiliar with lambda keys so this is something new to explore!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own max function that looks like that:

```
def max(list): 
   max=0
   for i in range (len(list)):
      if list[i][2]>max: //because in each of your list elements, the age is in third position
         max=list[i][2]
   return max
```

I always prefer to redefine event the easiest functions to be sure it does what I want

[EDIT]

Try this, it should work and return what you want

```
def max(list): 
   max=['','',0]
   for i in range (len(list)):
      if list[i][2]>max[2]: //because in each of your list elements, the age is in third position
         max=list[i]
   return max
```

Comment: This seems like the right path, however I get the error 
```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```
Is there somewhere I have to convert to str or int?